# How to answer a drop down with random answer

Tags: jquery

Suppose if my HTML is like below

```
<select>
         <option value="1">option 1</option>
         <option value="2">option 2</option>
         <option value="3">option 3</option>
         <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

How can I select one random answer from all the items.

Comment: Whatever happened to actually taking a stab at writing actual code before falling back to SO?

Comment: get all options, choose one randomly, select it. With which part did you have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $sel = $("select > option");
var $opt = $sel.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $sel.length));
alert($opt.text());  
// now do stuff with $opt
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLdnY/2

Answer (score 0):

Although you should be doing this on your own, here is relevant code:

```
<select id="test">
         <option value="1">option 1</option>
         <option value="2">option 2</option>
         <option value="3">option 3</option>
         <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('#test option').length);
   $('#test option').eq(random).attr('selected', 'selected');

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GL2A8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($("select option")[Math.floor(Math.random() * ($("select option").length + 1))]).prop("selected", true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j2Ck5/

Answer (score 0):

You can always select a random number from 1 to n (n = 4 in this case) and then set the select value to the number.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * $("select option").length) + 1);
$("select").val(randomNumber);
```